# ScrollView doesn't work - corona, lua

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

I'm trying to add object to the `ScrollView` and this is what happen:

> ERROR:Table expected. if this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':

What is that?

code:
This code is works:

```
    scrollView = widget.newScrollView  
        {                              -- ScrollView settings
            width = _W,
            height = 1760,
            horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
            hideBackground = true,
            friction = 0.988,
            x = display.contentCenterX,
            y = _H*0.55,
            isBounceEnabled = false,
            bottomPadding = 260,
            hideScrollBar = true
        }

for i = 1, #allballs do
            Frames[i] = display.newImage( "Frame.png" )
            Frames[i].height = 0.12*_H
            Frames[i].width = 0.38*_W
            Frames[i].ballImage = allballs[i].Image
            Frames[i].Purchased = allballs[i].Purchased
            Frames[i].Price = allballs[i].Price
            Frames[i].Place = i

            if (i%2==0) then
            Frames[i].y=(i-1)*140
            Frames[i].x = 0.27*_W
            PositionY = (i-1)*140
            PositionX = 0.27*_W
            else
            Frames[i].y=i*140
            Frames[i].x = 0.73*_W
            PositionY = i*140
            PositionX = 0.73*_W
            end

            if (allballs[i].Purchased) then
            balls[i] = display.newImage( allballs[i].Image )
            balls[i].height = 0.15*_W
            balls[i].width = 0.15*_W 
            balls[i].x = PositionX
            balls[i].y = PositionY  
            else
            local txtoptions = 
            {
            text = allballs[i].Price,     
            x = PositionX+0.055*_W,
            y = PositionY,
            width = 0.23*_W,  
            font = native.systemFontBold,   
            fontSize = _W*0.1,
            align = "left" 
            }
            balls[i] = display.newText( txtoptions ) 
            end      
            Frames[i]:setFillColor( 1, 1, 0.4 )
            Frames[i]:addEventListener( "tap", sellectball )
            scrollView:insert( Frames[i] )
            scrollView:insert( balls[i] )

     end
```

Everything works perfectly. But when I add this (between the ***):

```
for i = 1, #allballs do
            Frames[i] = display.newImage( "Frame.png" )
            Frames[i].height = 0.12*_H
            Frames[i].width = 0.38*_W
            Frames[i].ballImage = allballs[i].Image
            Frames[i].Purchased = allballs[i].Purchased
            Frames[i].Price = allballs[i].Price
            Frames[i].Place = i

            if (i%2==0) then
            Frames[i].y=(i-1)*140
            Frames[i].x = 0.27*_W
            PositionY = (i-1)*140
            PositionX = 0.27*_W
            else
            Frames[i].y=i*140
            Frames[i].x = 0.73*_W
            PositionY = i*140
            PositionX = 0.73*_W
            end

            if (allballs[i].Purchased) then
            balls[i] = display.newImage( allballs[i].Image )
            balls[i].height = 0.15*_W
            balls[i].width = 0.15*_W 
            balls[i].x = PositionX
            balls[i].y = PositionY  
            else
            local txtoptions = 
            {
            text = allballs[i].Price,     
            x = PositionX+0.055*_W,
            y = PositionY,
            width = 0.23*_W,  
            font = native.systemFontBold,   
            fontSize = _W*0.1,
            align = "left" 
            }
            balls[i] = display.newText( txtoptions ) 
      ***** coin = display.newImage( "coin.png", PositionX-0.07*_W, PositionY)
            coin.width = _W*0.05
            coin.height = _H*0.05 *******
            end      
            Frames[i]:setFillColor( 1, 1, 0.4 )
            Frames[i]:addEventListener( "tap", sellectball )
            scrollView:insert( Frames[i] )
            scrollView:insert( balls[i] )
   *******  scrollView:insert( coin ) ********

     end
```

It dosent work...

Comment: Could You please show some code and clarify version of Corona SDK, You're using? It seams, that You're accessing `ScrollView`  object in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youre probably calling the method like object.method() instead of object:method()
difference is that : syntax uses automatically *this* as reference to caller object, with . syntax you have to type it explicitly as first parameter

Comment: ok, I see where the problem can be. You are defining variable coin inside of the condition " if (allballs[i].Purchased) then" more specificaly in the "else" statement which probably never occures. Another thing is that youre defining global variable which always rewrites its own parameters and if the else statement wont activate in next cycle you will insert exact duplicate from previous cycle. Just put some print() statement inside the else branch and check if this one is processed, otherwise the coin will not be defined

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem: "You are defining variable coin inside of the condition " if (allballs[i].Purchased) then" more specificaly in the "else" statement which probably never occures."

Comment: Now i have another problem: the coin is under the frame so it cant be seen. I think it is because I insert the coin to the scrollview before the frame. What should I do?

Comment: OK I used: object:toBack() on the frames - Frame[i].toback

Answer (score 0):

The error always occurs for the reason like Andoloon pointed out.

but it doesn't seem to be in your ******* code. The problem for the ***** section might be that your 'coin' var is not a list, but it is defined and inserted in the loop. Try move it out of the loop and also remember to use local before the declearation.

Comment: I tried whith local and it doesnt work. the strange thing is that if I write the **** section outside the if/else it works...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that coin.png doesn't exist, or may not be an exact file name match (if you're doing this on a device).  Look for a warning in your console log about missing images.